# Clamping an objects movement between two radius

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I need help with math and clamping magnitudes. Lets say I have two radiuses that overlap at one point, like a venn diagram. How would I clamp an objects movement to only where the radiuses overlap?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private Vector3 _sphere1Center;
    private float _sphere1Radius;
    private Vector3 _sphere2Center;
    private float _sphere2Radius;

    private Vector3 CalculateNewPosition()
    {
       // Your movement system.
       return ...
    }

    private void UpdatePosition()
    {
        var newPosition = CalculateNewPosition();
        if (IsPointInsideBothSpheres(newPosition))
        {
            // Update position here.
        }
    }

    private bool IsPointInsideBothSpheres(Vector3 position)
    {
        return IsPointInsideFirstSphere(position) && IsPointInsideSecondSphere(position);
    }

    private bool IsPointInsideFirstSphere(Vector3 position)
    {
        return Vector3.Distance(_sphere1Center, position) <= _sphere1Radius;
    }

    private bool IsPointInsideSecondSphere(Vector3 position)
    {
        return Vector3.Distance(_sphere2Center, position) <= _sphere2Radius;
    }
```